# Probability AND/OR

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a bag of $10$ balls, and each ball is a unique colour.
If we randomly select $3$ balls from this bag, without replacement, I want to find out the chances of correctly guessing the colour of all $3$ balls (if we have chosen $3$ colours beforehand).

I have come down to two possible equations:
Work out the chances of not correctly guessing any ball and negate it:
$9/10 * 8/9 * 9/8 = 0.7$, where the complement is $0.3$

The chances of correctly guessing all balls:
$1/10 + 1/9 + 1/8 = 0.3361$

Firstly:
If these are both correct, which one is more accurate?

Secondly:
Is there a better way of calculating this?

I have a feeling I'm going about the whole thing in the wrong way, but I'm not too sure how I can check to be sure I'm heading in the right direction.

Comment: Just to clarify, does the order in which the balls are drawn matter? Can I predict the balls I am going to pull out are going to be blue, red, and yellow (in that order) and then I proceed to pull out the following balls: red, blue, and then yellow (in that order). Would this be allowed in your question? I did choose the correct colours, albeit not in proper order.

Comment: For the most part order does not matter, however while on the topic - Let's say that we are guessing green, red and blue. If the order of green and red did not matter but the order of blue must be the last (3rd) ball to get picked, would that be something similar to P(blue|2 balls have been picked)?

Comment: Yes. It would be P(blue on the third pick|(whatever ball was chosen for the second pick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose out of the ten colours, we predicted that we were going to pull out pink, red, and blue.

Then,

P(pink,red,blue)= P(pink on first pick)P(red on second pick|pink on first pick)P(blue on third pick|red on second pick)$=(\frac {1}{10})(\frac {1}{9})(\frac {1}{8})=\frac{1}{720}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we want to pick balls of colors red, white and black. The chances we will pick them are $\frac{1}{10} \frac{1}{9} \frac{1}{8}$.

Calculating the required probability by negation is a little more involved because you have to consider the situations that involve getting none of the desired colors, getting one red but no white or black, getting one white but no red or black etc.

Comment: Just to confirm, these are being multiplied together?

Comment: Yes. they are being multiplied.